# What hibernate second level cache contains immediately after the server start up?

Tags: database, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

What will be present in the hibernate second level cache immediately after the server startup and before firing any actual request. Will it be empty or will it read any data from the data base? Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be empty.

If you want it to be pre-loaded with data you have to write code that will load the data.